# how do i use WHERE with OR and OR in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-3.0

How can i perform queries like: `WHERE(a=1 OR b=1)AND (c=1 OR d=1)` in CAKEPHP 3.x ?

Am i supposed to use raw SQL for more advanced query ?

Answer (score 0):

Cake PHP like other PHP frameworks has his own [ORM](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) so you can map all your application model and programmatically call the database in order to execute CRUD operations.

I refer to the [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html) for an example

> **Quick Example**
>
> To get started you don’t have to write any code. If you’ve followed the CakePHP conventions for your database tables you can just start using the ORM. For example if we wanted to load some data from our articles table we could do:
>
> ```
> use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
>
> $articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
>
> $query = $articles->find();
>
> foreach ($query as $row) {
>     echo $row->title;
> }
> ```

Have a look at the [Query Builder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) section for more information. I suggest you to use this pattern instead of the raw query, expecially to prevent SQL injection.